# Python Matplotlib Boxplot Gaussian and Bootstrap

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is there a way to display a Gaussian and Bootstrapped boxplot on the same figure for the same data?

Code to create a series of box plots:

```
rtns = [rtn500, rtnaapl, rtnaxp, rtnba, rtncat, rtncsco]
tckr = ['SP500', 'AAPL', 'AXP', 'BA', 'CAT', 'CSCO']

tckr_color = ['xkcd:red', 'xkcd:green','xkcd:blue', 'xkcd:purple',
              'xkcd:dark grey', 'xkcd:pale green']

box_elements = ['boxes', 'whiskers', 'caps']

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,10))

bplot = ax.boxplot(rtns, patch_artist=True)
plt.setp(bplot['fliers'], marker='+')

for i in range(len(tckr)-1):
    for box_element in box_elements:
        plt.setp(bplot[box_element][i], color=tckr_color[i])

ax.yaxis.grid(True, alpha=0.5) #horizontal grid to read accross
ax.set_axisbelow(True)

ax.set_title('Stock Box Plots')
ax.set_xlabel('Stocks')
ax.set_ylabel('Returns')
ax.set_xticklabels(tckr, rotation=45, horizontalalignment='right')

fig.show()
```

This will create a single figure with standard confidence bands. I can create another figure with bootstrapped bands by passing the bootstrap=(int) argument to ax.boxplots(). But I would like to have them on the same graph in the order rtn500(std err), rtn500(bootstrapped err), etc. I tried using a loop:

```
rtns = [rtn500, rtn500, rtnaxp, rtnaxp, ...]
...
for i in range(len(rnts)):
    if i % 2:
        plt.boxplot(rtns[i], bootstrap=1000)
    else:
        plt.booxplot(rtns[i])
plt.show()
```

This will create the correct number of graphs, but they are all stacked on top of each other. I was thinking of going through the figures x locations and manually adjusting the spacing but that seems cumbersome.

Thanks,

Comment: Do you have an example of the plot you would like to make or some example data to work with?

Comment: Added some code snippets to the main question